# Directed Graph to DAG

Tags: graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph, microsoft-distributed-file-system

Does anyone have an algorithm for this problem? :
"Suppose we have a directed graph with n vertices and we want to make it acyclic.
How many sets of edges can we pick so that reversing the edges inside any one of those sets will make the graph acyclic?"
I can find the loops inside a graph,but i'm wondering if reversing one of edges of a loop , will produce another loop.